# preferredStatusBarStyle is not called after adopting SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, shortcutitems, preferredstatusbarstyle

I migrated AppDelegate functions to SceneDelegate.

`preferredStatusBarStyle` is not called when app is launched by ShortCutItems.

Flows

Step 1. ShortCutItems -> App Launched -> VC1 is presented with CustomNavigationController from UITabBarController

VC1's present style
modalTransitionStyle = crossDissolve
modalPresentationStyle = overCurrentContext

<- at this point, VC1's preferredStatusBarStyle is called

Step 2. Tap Button on VC1 -> navigationController?.setViewControllers([VC2], animated: true)

<- this point, VC1 is removed from navigationController and shows VC2

problem is VC2's preferredStatusBarStyle is not called

Here is my CustomNavigationController code:

```swift
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        topViewController
    }

    override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        topViewController
    }
}
```

Note:
AppDelegate with ShortCutItem was working fine.